# View.GoToDate doesn't go to date

Tags: vba, outlook

I tried to make my currentView go to specific date. the code runs but nothing happens on the window itself. the fields in the view objects doesn't change as well.

```
Dim oCV As Outlook.CalendarView    
Dim oExpl As Outlook.Explorer

Dim datGoTo As Date

Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
Set oCV = oExpl.CurrentView
datGoTo = "#03/01/2019#"
oCV.CalendarViewMode = olCalendarViewDay
oCV.GoToDate (datGoTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it by closing all folder except the one im trying to gotodate on...